# The Python zlib extension was not compiled on Mac OS X 10.11.1

Tags: python, zlib, osx-elcapitan

The following build error occurred when I build Python 2.7.11.

> ERROR: The Python zlib extension was not compiled. Missing the zlib?

My Build environment is:

- Mac OS X 10.11.1
- Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check here: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems. Try to reinstall your **command line tools**.

Answer (score 6):

I went through the same issue and what did the trick for me was:

1. (Re)install `zlib`:

```
$ brew reinstall zlib
```

2. Set its path to some env vars so compilers and `pkg-config` can find `zlib`:

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

3. Build Python again.

Comment: There's no need to install a second copy of zlib in macOS, and it may just confuse things down the line. Instead just point to the zlib that's already there and maintained by Apple. `xcrun --show-sdk-path` gives the path in which you will find `usr/include` and `usr/lib`.

Comment: What do the -L and -I stand for?

Answer (score 1):

I found the great answer.

Run below command in the terminal to install the command line developer tools.

> xcode-select --install

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/234

Answer (score 0):

if you update to new mac os version, you may need upgrade pyenv first.

brew reinstall pyenv

Answer (score 0):

When installing Python 2.7.18 in Mac M1 (Apple Silicon) with the new 'brew' version that works in '/opt/hombrew', not in '/usr/local/opt':

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"

arch -x86_64 pyenv install 2.7.18
```